# Find sides of triangle inside a circle, without trigonometric functions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

[image]
CED = $\angle 75 ^\circ$,
CDE = $\angle 60 ^\circ$,
DCE = $\angle 45 ^\circ$,
Radius = 1.

The question ask to find lenght CD, DE, EC without trigonometric functions.
What does it mean?

I tried using cosinus law, which is $CD = \sqrt{2r^2 -2r^2\cos 150^\circ}$
Does it mean i am using trigonometric functions?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: How about starting with the length of $CE$? Note, at this aim, that $\angle COE=120°$. What about $\angle EOD$?

Comment: Ok. I have tried..

Comment: $\angle EOD = 90^\circ$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter yes your try makes use of trigonometric functions, which is actually not strictly necessary in your case. Just work with Pythagorean theorem and specific right-angled triangles. Too late, you've got an explicit answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\measuredangle COE=120^{\circ}$, by the Pythagoras's theorem we obtain:
$$CE=2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt3.$$
Also, since $\measuredangle DOE=90^{\circ},$ by the  Pythagoras's theorem again we obtain:
$$DE=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt2.$$
Now, let $EF$ be an altitude of the triangle.

Thus, since $\measuredangle FED=30^{\circ},$ we obtain $$FD=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt2=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}.$$
Also, since $\measuredangle ECF=45^{\circ},$ we obtain $$CF=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$$ and

$$CD=FD+CF=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}.$$

Comment: You were satisfied with a very little effort from OP's side, after all :)

Comment: He got that $\measuredangle EOD=90^{\circ}.$ I think, it's $70$% of the problem.

Comment: No. I cannot end it...

Comment: oh. that way i also get the answer.. i thought it is considering using trigonometric functions?

Comment: I forgot how to calculate CE? What is 1/2 in phytagoras?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Since $\measuredangle CDE=60^{\circ}$, we obtain $\measuredangle COE=120^{\circ}.$ Now, let $K$ be a mid-point of $CE$. Thus, $\measuredangle COK=60^{\circ},$ $\measuredangle OCK=30^{\circ}$ and since $OC=1$, we obtain $OK=\frac{1}{2}.$ Id est, $CE=2CK=2\sqrt{OC^2-OK^2}=2\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt3.$

Comment: Why ock = 30 degree?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Because $OK$ also is an altitude of $\Delta OCE$ and $\measuredangle OCK=90^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=30^{\circ}.$

Comment: COK the same as EOK is 60?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Yes, of course!